# Nagios & Nc_net -> S.M.A.R.T

Tags: monitoring, windows-server-2012-r2, nagios

I need some help: We have a Nagios running which is monitoring some Windows 2012 R2 Servers. I want to add Disk Health/SMART-Monitoring to these machines.

The Nagios config for a service on a Windows Machine looks like this:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdkdh.png)

The Win Machines are running Nc_net. I can't replace that with another tool (like NsClient++). I searched a lot but couldn't find any **helpful** information. I also tried writing a script for Nc_net and tested smartmontools for windows. I would like to monitor Disk Health oder SMART Eroors in Nagios for all drives. Does anybody of you have the same scenario or can help me? I'm not that familiar with Nagios.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[check_wmi_plus](http://www.edcint.co.nz/checkwmiplus/) has a SMART health check mode. It doesn't require installation of an agent like NSClient++ or NC_net, as it uses the built-in WMI agent.

You do need to allow remote WMI execution, but [this is well documented](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagiosxi/docs/Monitoring-Windows-Using-WMI-and-Nagios-XI.pdf).

An example of a SMART check is [shown in the FAQ](http://www.edcint.co.nz/checkwmiplus/?q=faq_examplecommandlines).

Comment: Hi! Great answer so far - thanks for that! After 3 hours of configuring the windows machine, installing the python modules, compiling wmic and installing check_wmi_plus I came to a point where I am able to establish a WMI connection to my windows server. Running check_wmi with the checkmem command works perfectly but checksmart doesn't. I get this error:
http://imgur.com/Yd3fvp4

"ERROR: Login to remote object"

I did the steps from the tutorial on the windows machine and can't figure out what's wrong... Can you help me?

Comment: 80041003 is a permission error. Perhaps you need to use an admin account for checksmart?