# Windows Server - WMI Permission?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, wmi, smart

This question is related to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/739321/nagios-nc-net-s-m-a-r-t/739438) one.

I am trying to get some disk sensor data via WMI (W2012R2). Therefore I added a user **wmiagent** and granted some rights. I did it exactly like in [this](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagiosxi/docs/Monitoring-Windows-Using-WMI-and-Nagios-XI.pdf) guide.

Some commands like `checkmem` work fine so the connection is working to my Windows machine. But executing a `checksmart` command is giving me an error.

I figured out what whe WMI command is and tried to run it on my own. There output is:

```
ERROR: Login to remote object
```

[image]

The server is also a domain controller, maybe it's because of that?

Can you guys help me to get this working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The account also needs permission to logon.  Try granting it the "Allow logon locally" Windows right to the domain controller (Default Domain Controller Policy).